# ListView and TextFilter

Tags: android, listview, filter

When looking through the list of the given position is not correct. How to convey that I needed the position?
method **getItemId(position)** did not help!
There is some sample code:

```
lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
final String listcode[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
        R.id.product_name, listcode);

lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
            long id) {              

        long line = adapter.getItemId(position);
        Integer itemname = new Integer((int) line);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(Main.this, ShowKnot.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("defStrID", itemname.toString());
        b.putString("defStrName", listcode[itemname]);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {         
    Main.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
        int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
long line = adapter.getItemId(position);
```

you can use "position" in the method arguement returns the list item position number

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
        long id) {    

        a.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

here "int position" parameter is the index of the listitem.

Comment: I tried all the options and int and long but nothing works, it opens a wrong item when there were 140 items and then filtering them was 13, he counts from 0 to 12 when in the normal list the item at number 40.

Comment: I want to know what logic are you going 2 implement